# Where betwee dates in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, datepicker

Hi actually i am a beginner to laravel and i want to show a report between two dates depend on my records in db but i am very confused that how to do this can someone explain me how to do this like briefly what come in view , controller , model and route please its a great help to me because i am doing my final year project and tomorrow is the last date.
 my view is this but i dont know where to start

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
              <th>Header</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td>Lorem</td>
              <td>ipsum</td>
              <td>dolor</td>
              <td>sit</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          @endforeach
        </table>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you haven't given any information here so I will give a theoretical example.

Let's assume we have two dates:

```
$start = Carbon::now()->subWeeks(1);
$end = Carbon::now();
```

I am going to have a basic model called `Order` so that I can look at all orders submitted in my database in the last week. I am also assuming that there is a `created_at` field on the table.

```
$orders = Order::where('created_at', '>=', $start)->where('created_at', '<=', $end)->get();
```

This would return all orders between the dates supplied.

This logic would happen in the controller, then you can pass it to your view.

```
return view('orders.home', compact('orders'));
```